# Unable to connect to Azure Function App after integrating into VNET

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-function-app, vnet, azure-private-dns

**Problem Outline**

Azure Function App can not be accessed once it is integrated into a VNET and WEBSITE_VNET_ROUTE_ALL is set to 1.

This is required so that the Function App can securely connect to SQL without making the SQL publicly available.

**Errors:**

Unable to list Function App keys.

[image]

HTTP Request (CURL) from within VM in same network fails: 504 Gateway Timed out

[image]

**Architectural Diagram**

[image]

**Steps to reproduce**

1. Create a Resource Group
2. Create a VNET with 10.20.11.0/26 address space
3. Create a Subnet for the Function App to integrate into with address
   range of 10.20.11.0/27
4. Create a Linux Function App and integrated in the VNET you created
   in step 2.
5. See that App keys still loads as normal.
6. Create a Subnet for the database with address range of
   10.20.11.32/27
7. Create SQL Server and SQL Database.
8. Create a Private Link with DNS Zone on the Database and restrict
   public access.
9. Link DNS Zone to VNET created in step 2.
10. Function app resolved SQL private link as public IP address.
11. In the Function App configuration, add an Application setting
    WEBSITE_VNET_ROUTE_ALL and set it to 1.
12. See that Function app now resolves SQL private link as private IP
    address
13. See that Function App keys are not loading.
14. Attempt to connect to Azure Functions though a connection from the
    network or from public link.
15. See that Function app gateway times out.

Through an SSH connection into the Function App and with nslookup we determined that the connection to the private link resolves the local IP address of the SQL database as expected.

Setting the WEBSITE_VNET_ROUTE_ALL flag to 0, nslookup resolves the public IP of the SQL database.

As the SQL database is restricted and only available on the network, it is vital that the WEBSITE_VNET_ROUTE_ALL setting is set to 1.

WEBSITE_VNET_ROUTE_ALL = 1

[image]

WEBSITE_VNET_ROUTE_ALL = 0

[image]

**References**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet

Comment: What is your end question here, exactly? Is this actually related to programming, as the problem appears to be more related to Azure and permissions and functionality there, which may well not be on topic for SO.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was resolved by adding a "Microsoft.Storage" service endpoint to the Function App subnet.

When all of the traffic is sent into the vnet, it needs a service endpoint to Storage so that it can read the Function App configuration and functions.

1. Navigate to your Virtual Network resource
2. In the side menu, under Settings, select "Service endpoints"
3. Click on "Add"
4. Select "Microsoft.Storage" from the Service dropdown
5. Add policies if needed (I did not select any policies here)
6. Associate the Function App subnet
7. Add.

Comment: Could you elaborate please? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: @CB_Ron I added more detail. Hope it helps.

Comment: I had exactly the same problem like 3 months ago with almost the same configuration (difference was that I had private endpoint for an IoT Hub and not for an SQL database). I've tried to reproduce this error again (just to investigate some things) but now it works everytime even without service endpoint. Could you try to reproduce error from your initial question (so without adding service endpoint)? Because it looks like it might got fixed in the meantime (I think the necessity of adding Microsoft.Storage service endpoint wasn't documented anywhere).

Comment: thank you @Gerrit van Huyssteen,
you saved my day